# Assignment of a map variable's value to another variable

Tags: c++, boost, bitcoin

I have following code extract that irritates me a bit:

> CBlockIndex* pblockindex = mapBlockIndex[hash]; (1)

whereas:

- mapBlockIndex is a BlockMap variable

  - BlockMap is defined as follows:
    `typedef boost::unordered_map<uint256, CBlockIndex*, BlockHasher> BlockMap`

So my question is, since Blockmap creates map variables with 3 parameters (uint356, CBlockindex* and Blockhasher), how "C++ knows" which correct parameter to assign in (1)? I think it will neither assign BlockHasher's value nor uint256's value to pblockindex, but I don't know why?

### EDIT:

Maybe I should've explained my supposedly poor understanding of a map variable: I imagine map being (in this case) a triple of values. I'll put it into an example to make my question clearer: We introduce a variable sex of type Sex (plockindex, CblockIndex) and are assigning a map variables value to it - map variable john of type Human of type map. How do we assure that jsex is assigned to sex instead of jname or jage? Thanks for your patience :D

Answer (score 1):

The [`boost::unordered_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html) template arguments are

```
template<typename Key,
         typename Mapped,
         typename Hash = boost::hash<Key>, 
         typename Pred = std::equal_to<Key>, 
         typename Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, Mapped>> >
```

In your case, those template arguments are

```
boost::unordered_map<uint256, CBlockIndex*, BlockHasher>
//                   ^Key     ^Mapped       ^Hash

uint256       // Key
CBlockIndex*  // Mapped
BlockHasher   // Hash
```

So to answer your question, `BlockHasher` isn't used as the key, nor the mapped value. It is just a template argument for the Hash.

```
  CBlockIndex* pblockindex = mapBlockIndex[hash];
//             ^value        ^map          ^key
```

If this is still unclear look at [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

Notice in your case `Key` would be `uint256` and `T` would be `CBlockIndex*`. `Hash` would be `BlockHasher`, and `KeyEqual` and `Allocator` would be the defaults provided in the template.

**Edit**:
I think you are misunderstanding the template arguments. The map only works in this way: Given `key` find the corresponding `value`. All the other arguments help with implementation details. So in your case `jage` would be the key and `jname` would be the value. The third argument, `jsex` would be the hash function.

If you want a map that you can look things up by multiple keys, you need to modify your key. For example, let's say that we want to find a Human's sex, and we know their name and age, we can say

```
std::map<std::pair<std::string, int>, std::string> humans;
//            ^key(     ^name   ^age)      ^sex
```

So we could say

```
humans[{"David", 35}] = "male";
```

Note how the key is now a `std::pair` with multiple entries in it? This is because our `map` has the template specialization of

```
Key = std::pair<std::string, int>
T = std::string
```

The other template arguments `Hash`, `KeyEqual`, and `Allocator` are left to defaults.

Comment: Maybe I should've explained my supposedly poor understanding of a map variable: I imagine map being (in this case) a triple of values. I'll put it into an example to make my question clearer: We introduce a variable sex of type Sex (plockindex, CblockIndex) and are assigning a map variables value to it - map variable john of type Human of type map<jage, jname, jsex>. How do we assure that jsex is assigned to sex instead of jname or jage? Thanks for your patience, if I see to be dumb :D - I'm not a programmer.